# .htaccess 301 redirect from old RewriteRule to new

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with making a 301 redirection. I was using "flat" link system on website with RewriteRule:

domain.com/rubric-news
domain.com/article-815/news-title

```
RewriteRule ^rubric-([^*]*) news.php?kat=$1
RewriteRule ^article-([^*]*)/([^*]*)-([^*]*) article.php?id=$1&kat=$2&title=$3
```

Today I started to build better internal links system for SEO so now RewriteRules looks like this:

domain.com/news
domain.com/news/title-815

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ news.php?kat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^*]*)/([^*]*)-([^*]*) article.php?id=$3&kat=$1&title=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

now I should make 301 redirection from old links to the new ones and I don't know how to make it. Can anyone help me?))

Answer (score 0):

The redirect directives would follow exactly the same principles as you have already used for the rewrites. (Although there are potential issues with the rewrites/regex you are currently using - see below).

Try it like this before your existing rewrites:

```
# Redirect "/rubric-<news>" to "/<news>"
RewriteRule ^rubric-([a-z0-9]+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect "/article-<815>/<news>-<title>" to "/<news>/<title>-<815>"
RewriteRule ^article-(\d+)/(\w+)-(\w+)$ /$2/$3-$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have assumed your "id" parameter is all numeric (as per your example). (Although your existing directives do not enforce this.)

Any query string will be be passed through by default (you do not need the `QSA` flag here).

You should test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues. Clear your browser cache before testing.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^*]*)/([^*]*)-([^*]*) article.php?id=$3&kat=$1&title=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
> ```

The regex `[^*]*` matches anything that is not an asterisk (`*`) 0 or more times. You should be matching anything that is not a slash 1 or more times, ie. `[^/]+`. And you are missing the end-of-string anchor on the end of the regex (as you have on the preceding rule). With the very generic regex you are currently using (ie. `[^*]*`) this does not strictly matter, however, it is potentially ambiguous, ...

Your regex should be more restrictive (similar to the preceding rule). If your *id* consists of digits only then match only digits. If the *title* is only alphanumeric then match only letters and numbers, not everything. Currentrly it "looks like" the *news* and *title* parameters could contain hyphens, but that would introduce an ambiguity.

The `NC` flag is naturally superfluous here.

Consider something like this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)-(\d+)$ article.php?id=$3&kat=$1&title=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

If your *title* can contain hyphens then change the regex accordingly. eg. `^(\w+)/([\w-]+)-(\d+)$`